# Python Path Location Preference

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, standards, preference

NEWBIE QUESTION

Is there a preferred location for downloading a python distribution from `python.org` to a Windows10 PC?

I know that may sound like an odd question but I noticed the default path location seemed to be buried away in my file tree:

```
C:\Users\TW\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32
```

I was thinking of just installing it to:

```
C:\Program Files
```

So that the path is short and easy to get to. Is there anything wrong with this thinking? Is there a "Best Practices" approach here?

My experience with `Python/Objective`: I've been working with Python for a few months using the Spyder IDE. But I'd like to change it up and work in command line/VIM so now I have to install Python by itself to my machine and just want to make sure I am following best practice.

Thank you for you time.

Comment: If you have the requisite privileges, I don't think there's any harm to putting it in program files. Your IDE should take care of the hard stuff as long as you know where it is anyway

Comment: One my Windows machines, I always install it in `C:\python3` which is a very common location and very compatible and easy to work with. The Python installer will ask you where you want it installed when it's run.